# python is taking multiple column as index while importing csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, indexing, import

I am trying to import a csv file, the first column is dates, second is none, and the rest are some product data. When I import the file, it take my first three column as index. I just need to have dates as index.

[image: pic of my code]

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading the csv file by specifying the column names, all the columns that you didn't pass to the names argument will become an index. So you can either

1) Pass the name of the second and third index as the names argument which will give only the dates as index.

2) `Prd_data.reset_index(level=[1,2],inplace=True)`

This will drop the second and the third index and make them as columns and keep only the date as index.